# How to add the feature of adding wifi device or iot device in an app?

Tags: networking, aws-iot, samsung-smartthings, mobile-applications

I created an application on dyo appypie platform. The platform doesn't have the feature to add any WiFi or IoT device. I am having conversation with developer team, because it is dyo platform they can't give source code for the application as well. Is that true? Is there any way to get source code in this scenario.

Also mentioning I want to add a feature in my apl where I can monetize my IoT/Bluetooth/WiFi device. How can I get this done. They are advising I might need to built from scratch if their team doesn't come up with something.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit like saying "I want to use public transport so I don't need to buy a car and pay for its maintenance and gas, but I want to customise it".

Online platforms such as Appypie's allow you to build an app using the features they offer. If the feature you want is not included, then you can't include it, and you need to either find another platform which includes the feature(s) you want, or build it from scratch.

In any case, what does "adding a device" mean? Connecting to it? Sending data to it? Receiving data from it? What is your device? This is probably way too specific for any platform to offer the exact feature you want out of the box.

It is quite probable that your only option will be to build your app from scratch. But before you do that, you'll need to define exactly what your app should do, especially how it should communicate with your device.